# Replacing variables inside MATCH clause

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm working on an use case where labels of target nodes are dynamically requested by user. So my query is something like 
 `MATCH(x)-[:{relationship}]->(y:{label})`
I'm using spring-data-neo4j which i guess uses `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session` under the hood.

```
session.query(query, params)
```

I understand that params map is used to be able to replace params during run time and use same query template for performance reasons. 
But how can i use parameters to replace variables in `MATCH` clause. Not sure if this is some weird use case. But `{label}` is something i get per request basis.

How can i solve this problem.

P.S: I can do `String.format` before querying. Is there a better way?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j doesn't allow parametrized labels and relationship types.

You can use `labels(n)` and `type(r)` functions to use query parameters.

```
MATCH (x)-[r]->(y)
WHERE type(r) = {relationship} AND {label} in labels(y)
...
```

This will perform poorly when there is a large number of relationships of different type (Neo4j needs to scan and filter all relationships of a node, for `[r:TYPE]` it would traverse only relationships of given type).

So quite often the best option is to construct the queries at runtime - just make sure you have sanitized the input values to avoid *cypher injection* (similar to SQL injection).